# Set max number of map markers per day

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

In an app I limited total number of markers to 50, after which the user should delete markers to be able to pin more. Now I want to disable users from pinning large number of markers in a small time periods, I want to allow him to pin only 2 per day.
Code so far:

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
Marker marker; // Marker
int markerCount = 0; // Marker counter

//Add marker on long click
mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {

    int iMax = 50; // Max number of markers

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng arg0) {

        if (markerCount < iMax) {
            // start SendMessageActivity need to add marker to message activity
            startActivity(new Intent(MapsActivity.this, SendMessageActivity.class));

            markerCount = markerCount + 1;
            marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.custom_marker))
                    .position(
                            new LatLng(arg0.latitude,
                                    arg0.longitude))
                    .visible(true));
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Only " + iMax + " markers allowed at the same time",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest keeping a count in [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html), which is reset by an [Alarm](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) scheduled every day at 12:00 AM.

Comment: Let me know if you need any help - should be decently straight forward if you follow the official samples.

Comment: I am a beginner coder, and I'm going through documentation right now - I'm looking at preferences for my options tab. I think it is well documented, but thanks for the offer, if I get stuck I will let you know :)